Using pywin32 control AutoCAD
I am using pywin32 to control AutoCAD automatic through COM API. My code:
import pythoncom
import win32com.client
import pathlib
import random

detector = ['PersonA', 'PersonB', 'PersonC',]

check_stuff = ['PersonD', 'PersonE', 'PersonF',]

def vtInt(origin: list):
    return win32com.client.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_ARRAY | pythoncom.VT_I2,
                                   origin)

def vtVariant(origin: list):
    return win32com.client.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_ARRAY | pythoncom.VT_VARIANT,
                                   origin)

def main(root_dir: str):
    acad = win32com.client.Dispatch('AutoCAD.Application')
    acad.visible = True
    for road_dir in pathlib.Path(root_dir).iterdir():
        random_detector = random.choice(detector)
        random_check_stuff = random.choice(check_stuff)
        for dwg_file in pathlib.Path(road_dir).rglob('*.dwg'):
            acad.Documents.Open(dwg_file)
            time.sleep(2)
            try:
                acad.ActiveDocument.SelectionSets.Item('MySelection').Delete()
            except:
                acad.ActiveDocument.SelectionSets.Add('MySelection')

            my_selection = acad.ActiveDocument.SelectionSets.Item('MySelection')
            filter_type = vtInt([0, 8])
            filter_data = vtVariant(['Text', 'TK'])

            my_selection.select(5, 0, 0, filter_type, filter_data)

            for index in range(my_selection.Count):
                item = my_selection.Item(index)
                if 'Detector：' in item.TextString:
                    item.TextString = f'Detector：{random_detector}'

                if 'Check Stuff：' in item.TextString:
                    item.TextString = f'Check Sutff：{random_check_stuff}'

            acad.ActiveDocument.Save()
            time.sleep(1)
            acad.ActiveDocument.Close()
            time.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    st = time.time()
    root_dir = r'F:\VSCODE_PACKAGE\NormalUse32\Data'
    main(root_dir)

This code can be run, and it can iterate through the dwg files in the road_dir folder under the root_dir, replacing the specified text in the dwg files in each road_dir. But it can't work completely. When the code runs for a certain period of time, it may inexplicably trigger the following errors:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\VSCODE_PACKAGE\NormalUse32\Code\CADOperation\CAD_String_Replcae\main.py", line 147, in <module>
    main(root_dir)
  File "F:\VSCODE_PACKAGE\NormalUse32\Code\CADOperation\CAD_String_Replcae\main.py", line 69, in main
    for index in range(my_selection.Count):
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\VSCODE_PACKAGE\NormalUse32\.venv\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 638, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: Item.Count

Or:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\VSCODE_PACKAGE\NormalUse32\Code\CADOperation\CAD_String_Replcae\main.py", line 147, in <module>
    main(root_dir)
  File "F:\VSCODE_PACKAGE\NormalUse32\Code\CADOperation\CAD_String_Replcae\main.py", line 69, in main
    for index in range(my_selection.Count):
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\VSCODE_PACKAGE\NormalUse32\.venv\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 627, in __getattr__
    ret = self._oleobj_.Invoke(retEntry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 1)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147418111, 'Call was rejected by callee.', None, None)

My description means that code can process some dwg files first, but it always raise exception during operation and in the different file, can't fully operational. I don't know what happened and don't know how to solve it.
I use time.sleep to wait AutoCAD's connect, it doesn't work. When exception occurred, I process dwg file individually, it completely worked, that means error not come from dwg file. I think error may come from code or communicate with AutoCAD.

Well, I think I've solved this issue.My question maybe caused by COM connection was so weak and always be delays.So I use 'time.sleep' before the for loop of selection items,this small tricks seems solve this question.Until now,none of the exception were triggered.
